# Running PDO Statement in PHP returns bool(false)

Tags: php, pdo

I try to get a calculated value with this SQL Query in php: `$sql = "SELECT SUM(amount) as IncomeSum FROM income WHERE year = " . $year;`

The I try to fetch the result with PDO in this function:

```
function getDatafromDB($query, $columnName){
    require 'db.php';

    try {
        $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=$db_name", $db_user, $db_pass);

        $statement = $pdo->prepare($query);
        $retValue = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        var_dump($retValue);

        return $retValue[$columnName];
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        $error = "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";

        return $error;
        die();
    }
}
```

I call the function like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT SUM(amount) as IncomeSum FROM income WHERE year = " . $year;

$retValue = getDatafromDB($sql, "IncomeSum");
```

But when i `var_dump($retValue)` in the function above I always get

> bool(false)

as result.

Is there a problem with the alias name or something else wrong in my thinking?

Comment: Did you think about `execute()`ing the prepared query?

Comment: @AbraCadaver Do you mean `execute()` instead of `fetch()`?

Comment: No... prepare, execute then fetch.  See examples http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to execute() before you fetch().

```
$statement = $pdo->prepare($query);
$statement->execute();
$retValue = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Please read the code examples in the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php).